# JSON-LD to normal JSON

Tags: json, json-ld

I'm trying to insert a JSON-LD file into my CouchDB. The only problem I have is that when I insert my JSON-LD file, the resulting CouchDB is meaningless because the IDs aren't linked together.

An example of what my JSON-LD file looks like:

```
"contributor": [
{
    "@id": "_:N6e57c55b35b74782ada714fdc6d66bf1"
},
{
    "@id": "_:N810e115dfb3348579a7b826a7548095b"
}
```

And another part:

```
{
  "@id": "_:N6e57c55b35b74782ada714fdc6d66bf1",
  "@type": "Person",
  "label": "Isely, Duane, 1918-"
},

{
  "@id": "_:N810e115dfb3348579a7b826a7548095b",
  "@type": "Person",
  "label": "Cronquist, Arthur"
}
```

Now the IDs in "contributor" are linking to the two fields of the second part, which is describing person. I would like to know how to link them (the correct way), so I would get something like this:

```
"contributor": [
{
      "@type": "Person",
      "label": "Isely, Duane, 1918-"
},
{
      "@type": "Person",
      "label": "Cronquist, Arthur"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a JSON-LD processor to (re)create nicer JSON for your DB. A good possibility to prescribe the structure of JSON-LD documents is [to define a frame](http://json-ld.org/spec/ED/json-ld-framing/20120830/).

Quote from spec:

> JSON-LD Framing allows developers to query by example and force a specific tree layout to a JSON-LD document.

Example:

Assuming your document looks like

```
{
  "@context": {
    "contributor": {
      "@type": "@id",
      "@id": "http://purl.org/dc/terms/contributor",
      "@container": "@list"
    },
    "label": {
      "@id": "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel"
    }
  },
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@type": "MainResource",
      "@id": "_:foo",
      "contributor": [
        {
          "@id": "_:N6e57c55b35b74782ada714fdc6d66bf1"
        },
        {
          "@id": "_:N810e115dfb3348579a7b826a7548095b"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "@id": "_:N6e57c55b35b74782ada714fdc6d66bf1",
      "@type": "Person",
     "label": "Isely, Duane, 1918-"
    },
    {
      "@id": "_:N810e115dfb3348579a7b826a7548095b",
      "@type": "Person",
      "label": "Cronquist, Arthur"
    }
  ]
}
```

Add a JSON-LD Frame like

```
{
  "@context": {
    "contributor": {
      "@type": "@id",
      "@id": "http://purl.org/dc/terms/contributor",
      "@container": "@list"
    },
    "label": {
      "@id": "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel"
    }
  },
  "@type": "MainResource",
  "@embed": "always"
}
```

Throw it to a JSON-LD processor of your choice and you will get something like

```
{
  "@context": {
    "contributor": {
      "@type": "@id",
      "@id": "http://purl.org/dc/terms/contributor",
      "@container": "@list"
    },
    "label": {
      "@id": "http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel"
    }
  },
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@id": "_:b0",
     "@type": "http://json-ld.org/playground/MainResource",
      "contributor": [
        {
          "@id": "_:b1",
          "@type": "http://json-ld.org/playground/Person",
          "label": "Isely, Duane, 1918-"
        },
        {
          "@id": "_:b2",
          "@type": "http://json-ld.org/playground/Person",
          "label": "Cronquist, Arthur"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the complete example in [json-ld.org/playground](http://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-framed&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22contributor%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%2C%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2Fcontributor%22%2C%22%40container%22%3A%22%40list%22%7D%2C%22label%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2004%2F02%2Fskos%2Fcore%23prefLabel%22%7D%7D%2C%22%40graph%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22MainResource%22%2C%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Afoo%22%2C%22contributor%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3AN6e57c55b35b74782ada714fdc6d66bf1%22%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3AN810e115dfb3348579a7b826a7548095b%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3AN6e57c55b35b74782ada714fdc6d66bf1%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22Person%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22Isely%2C%20Duane%2C%201918-%22%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3AN810e115dfb3348579a7b826a7548095b%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22Person%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22Cronquist%2C%20Arthur%22%7D%5D%7D&frame=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22contributor%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%2C%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2Fcontributor%22%2C%22%40container%22%3A%22%40list%22%7D%2C%22label%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2004%2F02%2Fskos%2Fcore%23prefLabel%22%7D%7D%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22MainResource%22%2C%22%40embed%22%3A%22always%22%7D)

Unfortunately framing is not equaly well supported. So the result depends on the JSON-LD processor you're using.

You can elaborate further by removing "@" signs from your data. Simply add the following to your context:

```
"type" : "@type",
"id" :"@id"
```

Also, you can add shortenings for types to your context document

```
"MainResource": "http://json-ld.org/playground/MainResource"
```

See example in [json-ld.org/playground](http://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-framed&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22contributor%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%2C%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2Fcontributor%22%2C%22%40container%22%3A%22%40list%22%7D%2C%22label%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2004%2F02%2Fskos%2Fcore%23prefLabel%22%7D%2C%22type%22%3A%22%40type%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22%40id%22%2C%22MainResource%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fjson-ld.org%2Fplayground%2FMainResource%22%7D%2C%22%40graph%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22MainResource%22%2C%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3Afoo%22%2C%22contributor%22%3A%5B%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3AN6e57c55b35b74782ada714fdc6d66bf1%22%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3AN810e115dfb3348579a7b826a7548095b%22%7D%5D%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3AN6e57c55b35b74782ada714fdc6d66bf1%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22Person%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22Isely%2C%20Duane%2C%201918-%22%7D%2C%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22_%3AN810e115dfb3348579a7b826a7548095b%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22Person%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22Cronquist%2C%20Arthur%22%7D%5D%7D&frame=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22contributor%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%2C%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fpurl.org%2Fdc%2Fterms%2Fcontributor%22%2C%22%40container%22%3A%22%40list%22%7D%2C%22label%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2004%2F02%2Fskos%2Fcore%23prefLabel%22%7D%2C%22type%22%3A%22%40type%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22%40id%22%2C%22MainResource%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fjson-ld.org%2Fplayground%2FMainResource%22%7D%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22MainResource%22%2C%22%40embed%22%3A%22always%22%7D)

For full code java example with rdf4j look here: [How to convert RDF to pretty nested JSON using java rdf4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638342/how-to-convert-rdf-to-pretty-nested-json-using-java-rdf4j/43638343#43638343) .