# How to manipulate Json-ld?

Tags: semantic-web, json-ld

I've got this json-ld:

```
{ "@id":   "http://www.example.com/john-doe",
    "@type":   "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/Person",
    "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name":   "John   Doe",
    "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/age":   {
    "@value":   "42",
    "@kind":   "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#nonNegativeInteger"},
    "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/knows" : [
      {   "@id":   "http://www.example.com/charlie-brown"   },
      {   "@id":   "http://www.example.com/jane-doe"   }
    ]
  }
```

I have to write the context so that the below json-ld is valid.

```
{ "@context" : "context to write....",
  "@id":   "john-doe",
  "@type":   "person",
  "name":   "John   Doe",
  "age":   "42",
  "knows":   ["charlie-brown", "jane-doe"]
}
```

I've write a solution but it's incomplete, and I can't figure out how to write a full solution, hope that someone can help me.

Comment: 1) Do you mean `@type` instead of `@kind`? If not, where is `@kind` coming from? 2) Please share your incomplete solution, if possible. What *exactly* is it that you can’ŧ figure out? 3) Does your second snippet have to work exactly like this, or is it possible to change parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use [framing](http://json-ld.org/spec/ED/json-ld-framing/20120830/) to get a result close to your requirements.

- See this answer for a Java full code example, [How to convert RDF to pretty nested JSON using java rdf4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638342/how-to-convert-rdf-to-pretty-nested-json-using-java-rdf4j/43638343#43638343) .
- See also this answer that contains some extra tipps in addition [JSON-LD to normal JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42398060/json-ld-to-normal-json/42535395#42535395)

Use this [link for an example](https://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-framed&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2Fname%22%7D%2C%22age%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2Fage%22%7D%2C%22knows%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2Fknows%22%2C%22%40container%22%3A%22%40set%22%7D%7D%2C%22%40id%22%3A%22john-doe%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22person%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22John%20%20%20Doe%22%2C%22age%22%3A%2242%22%2C%22knows%22%3A%5B%22charlie-brown%22%2C%22jane-doe%22%5D%7D&frame=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2Fname%22%7D%2C%22age%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2Fage%22%7D%2C%22knows%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fxmlns.com%2Ffoaf%2F0.1%2Fknows%22%2C%22%40container%22%3A%22%40set%22%7D%7D%7D&context=%7B%7D) in json-ld playground. This is how your document with embedded @context would look like:

```
{
  "@context": {
    "name": {
      "@id": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name"
    },
    "age": {
      "@id": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/age"
    },
    "knows": {
      "@id": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/knows",
      "@container": "@set"
    }
  },
 "@id": "john-doe",
 "@type": "person",
  "name": "John   Doe",
  "age": "42",
  "knows": [
    "charlie-brown",
    "jane-doe"
  ]
}
```

This is, how the frame would look like

```
{
  "@context": {
    "name": {
      "@id": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name"
    },
    "age": {
      "@id": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/age"
    },
    "knows": {
      "@id": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/knows",
      "@container": "@set"
    }
  }
}
```

This will render to

```
{
  "@context": {
    "name": {
      "@id": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/name"
    },
    "age": {
      "@id": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/age"
    },
     "knows": {
      "@id": "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/knows",
      "@container": "@set"
    }
  },
  "@graph": [
    {
      "@id": "john-doe",
      "@type": "https://json-ld.org/playground/person",
      "age": "42",
      "knows": [
        "charlie-brown",
        "jane-doe"
      ],
      "name": "John   Doe"
    }
  ]
}
```