# How to traverse, navigate and access objects from a JSON-LD files with JSONLD-JAVA?

Tags: java, json, json-ld

I need to take a large JSON-LD file as input for an algorithm that I am writing in Java. Therefore, I intend to use JSONLD-JAVA for that.

The [JSONLD-JAVA](https://github.com/jsonld-java/jsonld-java) page shows an example for reading a JSON-LD file, but not for navigating or traversing it, or accessing individual objects in it. Instead, it refers to the [JSON-LD](https://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/) and [JSON-LD API](https://json-ld.org/spec/latest/json-ld-api/) specifications for details on specific possible operations.

However, the JSON-LD specification simply defines the syntax and semantics of a JSON-LD, and does not say anything about how to access them, and of course neither should it, being just a specification of the format. I was expecting that kind of operation to be described in the JSON-LD API specification, but it only describes operations that convert the entire JSON-LD file into different forms (compact, expanded, flattening, and conversion to RDF). It does not seem to include operations for accessing the objects (for example, accessing the key-value pairs of an object).

So I am guessing we are supposed to read the JSON-LD file and expand or flatten it, and then access it as pure JSON. But JSONLD-JAVA methods only return instances of `Object`, so it's not clear to me how I can use these object to obtain the JSON key-value pairs. The only exception seems to be the method `frame`, which returns a Map, but it is not very clear to me what a frame is. The JSON-LD specification does not include the word "frame", and the JSON-LD API specification has a very terse explanation which does not seem to help in understanding how to access an object's key-value pairs.

The fact that I only have Object instances from JSONLD-JAVA methods also makes it look like it would be hard to use some JSON library to use them, unless I use some JSON library that knows about the internal format of these objects as formed by JSONLD-JAVA, but the page of JSONLD-Java does not mention any such library.

I was expecting to be able to read a JSON-LD file and then programmatically accessing or manipulating it within Java, and to have Java classes that correspond to the main concepts, something like a `JSONLDObject` with methods for providing its key-value pairs.

As I read the above pages, I get the feeling that they are meant for people that already know something that I don't. So perhaps I am missing something. Otherwise, is there a tutorial on using JSONLD-JAVA or even just the JSONLD API in order to traverse the objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you read the documentation on the [JSONLD-JAVA](https://github.com/jsonld-java/jsonld-java) page you linked to, it starts with a **commented** example:

```java
// Open a valid json(-ld) input file
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("input.json");
// Read the file into an Object (The type of this object will be a List, Map, String, Boolean,
// Number or null depending on the root object in the file).
Object jsonObject = JsonUtils.fromInputStream(inputStream);
// Create a context JSON map containing prefixes and definitions
Map context = new HashMap();
// Customise context...
// Create an instance of JsonLdOptions with the standard JSON-LD options
JsonLdOptions options = new JsonLdOptions();
// Customise options...
// Call whichever JSONLD function you want! (e.g. compact)
Object compact = JsonLdProcessor.compact(jsonObject, context, options);
// Print out the result (or don't, it's your call!)
System.out.println(JsonUtils.toPrettyString(compact));
```

The second comment is interesting, so let me highlight it for you:

> **Read the file into an `Object` (The type of this object will be a `List`, `Map`, `String`, `Boolean`, `Number` or `null` depending on the root object in the file).**
>
> ```java
> Object jsonObject = JsonUtils.fromInputStream(inputStream);
> ```

The key point is that JSONLD is **JSON**, and that when you've loaded it into memory like above, you can navigate that **JSON** structure, by casting the `Object` as appropriate.

Lets have a look at Example #3 from the [JSON-LD specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/):

```
{
  "@context":
  {
    "name": "http://schema.org/name",  // ← This means that 'name' is shorthand for 'http://schema.org/name' 
    "image": {
      "@id": "http://schema.org/image",  // ← This means that 'image' is shorthand for 'http://schema.org/image' 
      "@type": "@id"  // ← This means that a string value associated with 'image' should be interpreted as an identifier that is an IRI 
    },
    "homepage": {
      "@id": "http://schema.org/url",  // ← This means that 'homepage' is shorthand for 'http://schema.org/url' 
      "@type": "@id"  // ← This means that a string value associated with 'homepage' should be interpreted as an identifier that is an IRI 
    }
  }
}
```

So if you want the `@id` value of the `image`, you'd do this:

```java
Map<String, Object> root = (Map) jsonObject;
Map<String, Object> context = (Map) root.get("@context");
Map<String, Object> image = (Map) root.get("image");
String imageId = (String) image.get("@id");
```

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Convert JSON-LD to a nice nested map. Use the framing algorithm. Example: [JSON-LD to normal JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42398060/json-ld-to-normal-json)
and [How to convert RDF to pretty nested JSON using java rdf4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638342/how-to-convert-rdf-to-pretty-nested-json-using-java-rdf4j/43638343#43638343)

**2.** Accessing JSON-LD. I would use [JsonNode](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) together with [JPointer](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-appsawg-json-pointer-03).
On small and simple documents operating directly on the `Map<String,Object>` is also ok. For JsonPointer you can use [Jackson JsonNode.at()](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#at(java.lang.String)).

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode json = mapper.readValue(in, JsonNode.class);
String id = json.at("/@id").getText();
```

**3.** Preprocessing. In some cases it can be handy to preprocess the JSON Input. This answer lists some command line tools: [XSLT equivalent for JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618038/xslt-equivalent-for-json/49011455#49011455)