# How rename the @id in Json ld Context - API Platform [Resolved]

Tags: api, symfony, json-ld, api-platform.com, hydration

I am working for an API and I have a problem with my Json-ld
Is it possible to change the @id in the Json-ld Context ?

Entity :

```
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *      normalizationContext={"groups"={"question_get"}},
 *      denormalizationContext={"groups"={"question_post"}},
 *      itemOperations={
 *          "get" = {
 *              "enable_max_depth"=true,
 *              "force_eager"=false,
 *          },
 *          "put" = {
 *               "denormalization_context"={"groups"={"question_put"}}
 *          }
 *      },
 *      collectionOperations={
 *          "get"= {
 *                   "normalization_context"={"groups"={"questions_get"}},
 *               },
 *          "post"
 *      },
 *      attributes={
 *          "enable_max_depth"="true",
 *          "pagination_client_items_per_page"=true,
 *      },
 *  )
 */
class Question
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

  ...
```

Json :

```
"@context": "/api/contexts/Question",
  "@id": "/api/questions",
  "@type": "hydra:Collection",
  "hydra:member": [
    {
      "@id": "/api/questions/32",
      "@type": "Question",
      "id": 32,
     ...
```

And what I Want :

```
  "@id": "/questions"
```

I want to keep route "/api/question", I'm only looking for change the @id of my entity but not relation.

**Edit:** I found a way, I use a normalizer : https://api-platform.com/docs/core/identifiers/#custom-identifier-normalizer

```
#App\src\Serializer\ApiNormalizer.php

...

 public function normalize($object, $format = null, array $context = [])
    {

        $data = $this->decorated->normalize($object, $format, $context);

        $data['@id'] = substr($data['@id'], 4);

        return $data;

    }

...
```

Comment: https://api-platform.com/docs/core/extending-jsonld-context/

Comment: Thank you but It's working for a variable, but i'm looking for an entity.

Comment: Sorry, but did you read the whole page?

/**
 * ...
 * @ApiResource(itemOperations={
 *     "get"={"hydra_context"={"foo"="bar"}}
 * })
 */
class Book ..............

and you mean a property not a variable ^^. 
And properties can be entities instead of an varaible value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide an alias/shortening in your context:

```
"type" : "@type",
"id" :"@id"
```

This allows you to get rid of `@`-signs in your documents and in your code. [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42535395/1485527)

Comment: Thanks, it's a better way indeed. I will use this