# What does mean @id and @type in json-ld context?

Tags: json, json-ld

What does mean this statement in json-ld context?

```
{
  "@context": {
      "@version": 1.1,
      "id": "@id",
      "type": "@type"
  }
}
```

and

```
{ 
   "@context": {
       "id":   {"@type": "@id", "@id": "@id"},
       "type": {"@type": "@id", "@id": "@type"}
   }
}
```

I do not figure out that expression means what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Json-Ld](https://w3c.github.io/json-ld-syntax/) is designed to be interoperable with [rdf](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/). Therefore it introduces certain keywords marked with `@`. This keywords are needed to create [rdf-statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49066324/1485527) from the json document.

A good starting point to get familar with the underlying concepts is to play around with the [Json-Ld Playground](https://json-ld.org/playground/). You will find some examples there. You can use the examples to create conversions from one format into another.

**Getting rid of the '@'-character**

[Sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42398060) the '@'-character can become unhandy, e.g. when working with Javascript. In such situations it is possible to define an alias for an '@'-keyword. Like shown in your context:

```
{
  "@context": {
      "id": "@id",
      "type": "@type"
  }
}
```

By defining aliases for '@'-keywords the actual json document is easier to consume by non-rdf applications while it is still possible to process the data as rdf.